# Combine ReLU with TanH is a good idea?

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, tensorflow, gan, generator

I have a CNN implementation for the Generator of a GAN, internally, the architecture is using ReLU for non-linearities, but at the output, the paper of the architecture specifies Tanh must be used.

The paper doesn't specify if ReLU must be used on the internal layers or not. But I'm concerned that the Relu is basically dropping out the negative side and when it reaches Tanh, it is lowering the quality of the Data, maybe I'm wrong, but can't find online anything concrete, specific to this question.

This is the paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.03826.pdf

Thanks in advance!

PD: what I mean with "lowering the quality" is that, with Relu, the network adapts internally to work with values > 0.0, but when the flow reaches the output, it must suddenly adapt to a new range -1.0 - 1.0, my insight is that this can be disruptive, maybe I'm wrong

PD2: As an extra, the discriminator receives these normalized images in the range -1.0, 1.0 but it uses LeakyReLU for the convolutions, is that something viable?

Comment: The biggest reason to not use tanh is that it creates vanishing gradients. If the authors don't comment on why they chose this particular configuration of activations, it will be difficult to discern why they chose it. The only thing that springs immediately to mind is that tanh is bounded above and below, while ReLU is only bounded below. Is boundedness important to this GAN?

Comment: Actually, this is what they say: "The input images are normalized to [-1 1]. We also use a Tanh activation layer to keep the output in the same range" This is regarding the generator part of the GAN

Comment: maybe normalize the images to [0, 1] and use only ReLUs can be a good option?

Comment: And about boundedness, I feel that maybe they are important because the ultimate target of all this is to predict images from the generator architecture, and having boundaries allows for easier parsing to int8 images natural type? Maybe don't having boundaries can produce oversaturate images on the high side of the pixel color space

Comment: Sounds like you’ve answered your question: the authors are trying to hit a target normalized to a specific interval that matches the codomain of tanh.

Comment: What can I do with internal ReLUs? maybe swapping them for LeakyReLUs can alleviate the domain differences between the output and the internals?

Comment: Has it been established that the differences creates optimization problems? I’m not convinced that this network would exhibit problems that are not the generic problems that GAN optimization has.

Answer (score 0):

The weights and bias should be able to resolve the difference between the 2 functions in regards to processing negative numbers. So for example, the internal Relu functions will out put only positive numbers, but as those numbers feed to Tanh output, the weights will convert them into a negative number which Tanh can handle.

Example

> Relu -> 0.2  -> weights(0.2 * -0.01) = -0.002 -> Tanh -> out negative

Now if you are feeding in negatives to Tanh and then feeding to Relu and wanting negative numbers to come out, this won't work. But let's say you are only out putting positive numbers, you can still start with negative inputs and Tanh. The negative numbers can be converted to positive and subtracted from other vectors to reduce the positive out put.

The downside I can see to this (not considering vanishing gradients, dead neurons) is simply adding inefficiency to the network by giving it extra computation to do internally.

Answer (score -1):

We reach the conclusion that having ReLU inside the network and Tanh at the output does not cause any performance problem.

Comment: Can you expand on this? How do you know that having ReLU inside the network and tanh as the output does not cause a performance problem? How are you measuring performance, and how are you deciding if there is a problem? Please [edit] to elaborate.